# Plain text editor that supports vertical text (for Chinese, Japanese, etc)

Tags: windows, text-editor, cross-platform, language, unicode

I would be interested to find a plain text editor that provides a mode for **vertical text**.

**Chinese** and **Japanese** can both be written either left-to-right in rows going from top to bottom, or top-to-bottom in columns going from right to left.  There are editors for formatted documents which support these, such as Microsoft Word.

But from time to time I have a need to type **plain old unformatted text** vertically in Chinese and Japanese.

- Whereas a formatted document editor would allow both horizontal and vertical within a document using its layout and markup systems, a plain text editor would just have it as a viewing mode.
  (much like being able to select a font or turning word-wrap on and off.)
- It doesn't matter how inline English or other languages are rendered
  (letters rotated 90° or not), though more options are better than fewer.
- It should work with the standard IMEs that ship with the OS.
- Unicode should be supported, including supplementary plane support.
  (UTF-8 or UTF-16 but must not mangle surrogate pairs or save as ASCII silently converting everything to `?` marks)
- Really should have installer and user interface in **English**.
  Even though I know how to type several languages, I can't actually speak or read them so menus, preferences, installer, etc should be available also in English.

I have also wanted to type vertical **Mongolian** script recently and it is a bit different: top-to-bottom in columns going from left to right. An editor which supported this mode would be best of all, but editors without it are also acceptable.

I'm using Windows 7 but I have a preference for open source, cross platform software.

Comment: VerticalEditor might fit if outliners are OK. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outliner

Comment: Related network questions: [Which word processors and websites supports vertical writing of Chinese?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/39044/8099) (Chinese.SE) and [Vertical Chinese text with XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38577/47311) (TeX.SE).